# Why is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{ n+1 \choose n }x^{n} = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$ when computing recurrences with generating functions?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

Like the title says. I don't know how one gets from $G(x) = \frac{2}{1-2x} - \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$ to $G(x) = 2\sum2^nx^n - \sum{n+1 \choose n}x^n$. I know this gives $a_{n} = 2^{n+1}-n-1$. I get the first term getting to $2^{n+1}$, but how does the second term work out? Moreover, what would $\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}$ or $\frac{1}{(x-1)^3}$? I don't know how to translate them when the quantity is raised to a power or when the 1 in the denominator is negative. Please help. Thank you

Comment: The title says something which isn't true, so "like the title says" isn't helpful.

Comment: Presumably, you mean "Why is  $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+1}{n}x^n=\frac1{(1-x)^2}?$"

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, that's what I mean

Comment: $$\frac1{(1-x)^2}=(1-x)^{-2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{-2}n(-x)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\binom{-2}nx^n$$ $$(-1)^n\binom{-2}n=\binom{n+1}n=\binom{n+1}1=n+1$$

Comment: $$\frac1{(1-x)^2}=\frac d{dx}\frac1{1-x}=\frac d{dx}\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)x^n$$

Comment: If that is what you mean, edit your question. An answerer shouldn't need to read the comments to understand your question.

Comment: @bof thanks so much. This makes much more sense now. I appreciate it.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I thought editing was frowned upon. I'm new to this platform. The question is edited.

Comment: @JohnDixon Editing to change a question completely is frowned upon, but editing to fix a wrong question is encouraged.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer**

We have the following expression:

$$
\left(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^{i}\right)^{2}
=
\sum_{a=0}^{\infty}\sum_{b=0}^{\infty}x^{a+b}
$$

Now let's group the summands on the RHS based on the value of $a+b=n$ where $n\in\{0,1,2,...\}$. Using stars and bars, the number of integer solutions to $a+b=n$ is $\binom{n+1}{1}=\binom{n+1}{n}$. Therefore, the expression can be written as:

$$
\left(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^{i}\right)^{2}
=
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+1}{n}x^{n}
$$

The LHS is equivalent to $\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)^{2}$

**Generalization**

$$
\left(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^{i}\right)^{m}
=
\sum_{a_{1}=0}^{\infty}
\sum_{a_{2}=0}^{\infty}
...
\sum_{a_{m}=0}^{\infty}
x^{a_{1}+a_{2}+...+a_{m}}
$$

Again, using stars and bars, the number of integer solutions to $a_{1}+a_{2}+...+a_{m}=n$ is $\binom{n+m-1}{m-1}$. Therefore the expression is equivalent to:

$$
\left(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^{i}\right)^{m}
=
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+m-1}{m-1}x^{n}
$$

The LHS is equal to $\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)^{m}$

Comment: Thanks so much. I appreciate your response.